# Nginx fails to load JS files but loads CSS

Tags: nginx, vanilla-forums

I have setup a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04, Ajenti panel + Agenti V. Now I am trying to move an installation of Vanilla Forums from one server to another and it's giving me some headaches.

The forums open just fine, I can go through pages, **.css files are loading but not .js files**.

This is my nginx configuration in Ajenti:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1;
}

location ~ .(js|jpg|png|css)(.+)$ {
  root /srv/anunes/spacacores/;
}
```

The last part is my solution attempt. It does nothing.

Comment: Can you past full links to js and css files ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me answer this question without links then :)

`.(js|jpg|png|css)(.+)$`

This regex says:
Any character followed by one of `js|jpg|png|css` ending with one, or more character(s).

Lets change regex to: `\.(js|jpg|png|css)(.*)$` and restart nginx and then try it again.

Why?
Probably your `js` links has format `file.js?something` and css files does not, so nginx doesn't match `main.css` at all because it has no character(s) after `css` part (which is required by `.+` regex's part).